# Why is Magento admin page in redirect loop?

Tags: php, magento

I have installed Magento on XAMPP localhost. The installation was successful and homepage was working. But when I tried to access the admin page, I got the following error in Chrome:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS,
The webpage at http://localhost:8080/Shoeshop/admin/admin/index/index/key/af5bf0c229a918e3ecb4352ef4eee8014f1a580611c285326f659992f6bb7107/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.`
```

and when I check the console  for errors:

[image: console output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.. try with different browser , mozilla worked for me.

Comment: I was having the same issue on he admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do:

Check your `.htaccess` for any loops - [find a sample here](https://github.com/nexcess/magento/blob/master/.htaccess.sample) if you can't tell what's wrong.

Truncate the table (empty it, not delete!) `core_url_rewrite` using PHP My Admin or equivalent.

Lastly, if none of the other techniques work. Check your site configuration via XAMP, Directory options such as `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` must be specified. [See here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04) for a tutorial about a magento site setup. Note: this assumes you have apache2 installed and Linux version is (or resembles) Ubuntu 14.04.

Hope this helps.